# Android studio cannot find device when I run my program

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried everything I can think of and everything I have looked up online. None get me progress. On the phone I have activatied developer mode, I am using a cord that can transfer files, and I have given computer permission to access my phone. On the computer end I have updated every thing I can think of and I am able to see my phones storage from it but the device does not appear on android studio.

The laptop runs on Windows 8 (unfortunately).
Ask if any other info is needed.

Thank you in advance, I'm getting desperate.

Comment: Did you install your phone's usb drivers?

Comment: Yes I have done this.

Comment: Have you on Usb Debugging from Developer Option ?

Answer (score 0):

## CHECK IF YOUR DEVICE API LEVEL IS LOWER THAN THA APP MINIMUM API LEVEL

it might happen that the app you are building is build for a higher android-version. like if you are building an app for api 21 and your device is have api level 17 then it wont show your device in the list of connected devices. once i faced this problem

Comment: Must they be exactly the same. ( I believe they are but I can recheck) :)

Comment: i think this is the problem in your case

Comment: your device API level is greater then the minimum supported API of app

Comment: @BaileyAnderson what happend ?

Comment: @Mushtak he has mentioned that in question that he has enabled devs mode